# Android won't connect to wifi after MAC address changed

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address

I have an HTC inspire rooted android that is running primos Rom. After I changed my MAC address using "ip link set wlan0 address" and then the MAC address, my phone would no longer connect to my password protected WiFi. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Password protection isn't related to MAC address change.

> 1. Verify that your new MAC address is in the valid format:
>      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details
> 2. Check your router settings and make sure you don't have MAC filtering enabled The router might've been configured to accept only predefined MAC addresses or range of them.
> 3. Flush your arp cache. This will release any binding that might exist between your old MAC address and your assigned IP.
> 4. Release and renew you IP.

BTW, MAC address is a property associated with a specific device at manufacturing. Normally, you shouldn't change it.